# Android - ListActivity not triggering onListItem clicks

Tags: android, xml, listview, listactivity, onitemclicklistener

A lot of people had this same issue before, but I haven't been able to solve it using their solutions..

I've got a ListActivity with a custom ArrayAdapter, but I can't seem to trigger the onItemClick.

I've tried it both with the default `@Override protected void onListItemClick(...)` which didn't trigger, and also with a `myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){ ... });`, which also didn't work.

From previous stackoverflow questions regarding this matter I've used the following pieces of code in the xml:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"`
```

In the list_item.xml views

Or `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` in the ListView itself.

Here below is the main part of code regarding this problem:

ChecklistActivity.java:

```
public class ChecklistActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private List<Product> products;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist);

        // test products:
        products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            Product p = new Product();
            p.setName("Product " + i);
            products.add(p);
        }

        MyAdapter adapt = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_inner_view, products);
        setListAdapter(adapt);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapt, View v, int position, long id){
                onListItemClick(v);
            }
        });

        ...
    }

    private void onListItemClick(View v){
        Log.i("CHECKLIST ACTIVITY", "onListItemClick triggered");

        ...
    }
```

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/checkbox_content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_background"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_product_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, very stupid of me.. I removed

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

from the LinearLayout of the list_item.xml and now it works..